# Change the default port that Nagios monitors a well-known service on

Tags: ubuntu, port, nagios, sshd

Just installed Nagios 3.2 and have it monitoring 4 or 5 windows hosts as well as itself. The localhost (Ubuntu 10.04) has SSHD configured, but I've changed the port it's listening on. Nagios hates this.

How do I change the port that Nagios checks to see that my SSH server is functional?

I've spent quite some time RTFM and ♫♪ I still haven't found what I'm looking for ♫♪.

Comment: This is not a programming-related question, hence it doesn’t belong on Stack Overflow. Consider flagging it for migration to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the output of `check_ssh -h` ? You can use the `-p` option to specify the port. Or use `check_tcp` with the same option for a more generic check.